# Making sure that subscription is closed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service, that gets data from 2 sources and then does some logic on it and on top of that, I have a component that uses this service and should be notified when this logic is done. I actually have working example for this, however I'm not entirely sure if my subscriptions are closed.

Firsly, the service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private myData: string[] = [];

  load(): Observable<any> {
    return combineLatest([this.loadInternal1(), this.loadInternal2()]).pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(next => {
        this.myData.push(next[0].map(el => el.toUpperCase()));
        this.myData.push(next[1].map(el => el.toLowerCase()));
      })
    );
  }

  private loadInternal1(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(['data', 'data2']);
  }

  private loadInternal2(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(['data3', 'data4']);
  }
}
```

And then component

```
export class HelloComponent {
  loading: boolean = true;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    const sub$ = this.appService.load().subscribe(next => {
      console.log(next)
      this.loading = false;
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(sub$.closed);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

From what I heard, `take(1)` should automatically close subscription after first emitted value, so I don't have to close it manually.

I wanted to check this, so after 1 second I'm making sure if `sub$.closed === true`, and yes - it is.

However, when I remove `take(1)` line from my service implementation, it is closed as well... So I'm confused - do I need this at all? Or maybe I don't understand how subscriptions work exactly...?

#Edit:

This subscription is not happening on constructor but on click, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <button (click)="getData()">Get data</button>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnDestroy {
  loading: boolean = true;
  sub$: Subscription;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub$.unsubscribe();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.sub$ = this.appService.load().subscribe(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

The question is - what is happening with `private sub$` on each click? It gets reassigned, correct? So it means it automatically gets completed as well?

If user clicks 10 times, then he will create 10 subscriptions and 9 of them will be closed. Then, on closing the page for example, `ngOnDestroy` will be trigger and will close the 10th one?

Answer (score 0):

If you unsure about that you can do only

exports class Component implements OnDestroy{

whatever you write here you can destroy all of that things. That you have doubt.

ngOnDestroy(){
All data destroyed. when component close.
}
}

Answer (score 0):

startly don't subscribe in the constructor. is not a good practice, and some times can cause strange behavior (eg sometimes some data are not ready when the constructor start). use ngoninit instead.

then you have to unsubscribe the subscription. i use this way:

```js
export class HelloComponent {
  loading: boolean = true;
  
  subscriptions = new Subscription; //this is like a "container" of my subscription
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  const sub$ = this.appService.load().subscribe(next => {
      console.log(next)
      this.loading = false;
    });
   
   this.subscriptions.add(sub$); //you have to add every subscription to our subscriptions
   
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscriptions.unsubscribe() //when the component is destroyed the subscriptions is "closed"
  }
```

however if you want to unsubscribe at certain moment, you can do something like this

```js
export class HelloComponent {
  loading: boolean = true;
  
  private destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject();
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  const sub$ = this.appService.load().pipe(
   takeUntil(destroy$) //when you cast destroy$ the observable unsubscribe the subscription
  )
  .subscribe(next => {
      console.log(next)
      this.loading = false;
    });
   
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.destroy$.next()
    }, 1000);
   
  }
```

answering to your edit:

i'm not so expert, so i'm not really sure if i'm saying rigtt, but when you click, you don't create new subscription. the subscription is only one, and it remains listening the load observable emit data. if user click ten times, 20 100 times, the subscription is only one, and until you don't trigger the stream he don't do nothing.

if i understand your purpose i show you a service that help me refetch data in some case

myservice.ts

```js
export class DossierService {
  ....

  fetchData$$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);

  constructor() {}

  onReload() {
    this.fetchData$$.next();
  }

  isReload(): Observable<void> {
    return this.fetchData$$.asObservable();
  }
```

in component i'll do

```js
...

ngOnInit() {
  const dossier$ = 
   this.dossierService.isReload().subscribe(...mylogic);
this.subscriptions.add(dossier$)
}

refetchData() {
 this.service.onReload()
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscriptions.unsubscribe()
}
```

the subscription is only one, that i trigger every time i call refetchData(), that in service push the subject

Comment: It was only example with constructor, in real code it actually happens on click. In that case, each click will create new subscription and will reassign the `private subscription`, is that correct? And in that case, each reassignment will close this subscription? And last one will be destroyed in `ngOnDestroy`"?

Comment: i need some code to understand well. but every time you trigger a stream it change, but the subscription is only one,  is the stream of data that change.